# Magento 2 on Multi Server Architecture vs CI/CD

Tags: magento2, server-setup

I have set setup of magento on multi server in AWS with loadbalancer - when there is cpu load of more than 80 percent new server is auto created with Base server images on specific time

I am facing below issue and need help with solutions

1: When new autoscaled server is launched code of that is not updated one like if we modify some code it is not there in new autoscaled server -- how to solve this issue

a: Will CI/CD fix this issue ? , how will CI/ CD take care of dynamically created generated folder
b: how can i show latest css files in pub static folder

please help with above should we go with NFS ? or mount bucket as alternative to CI/CD

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use NFS for file sharing. so whenever there is new server will create it will use files from nfs server.

Comment: can you help with what all directory should be used for NFS , will NFS increase any latency or performance issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to share some content between ec2 nodes
Simple solution is [shared volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html)

You need to link `var` and `pub/media` directories to attached volume on each node

Better to support actual codebase on all nodes each deploy

I recommend to use Redis for [cache](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/redis/redis-pg-cache.html) and [sessions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/redis/redis-session.html). You can create Redis instance in AWS.

Don't forget to actualize for each node or share `app/etc` files

Comment: do you mean nFS storage as shared storage ?

Comment: In this case it's a solution called [AWS Volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes.html) which you can manage in AWS console.

Comment: we are using gcp can you tell what is it called in GCP

Comment: See [Add Persistent Disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) and [Share persistent disks between VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/sharing-disks-between-vms)

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk  With use of either AWS Volume  or  Persistent Disk  mean we are still at a possible 'single point of failure' problem for the application?  When the SHARED ANYTHING is not available?

Comment: @WilsonHauck See [How to Remove Single Points of Failure by Using a High-Availability Partition Group in Your AWS CloudHSM Environment](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-remove-single-points-of-failure-by-using-a-high-availability-partition-group-in-your-aws-cloudhsm-environment/) for AWS. Not sure about GCP persistent disks, need to check in details. I have much bigger experience with AWS, and luckily I didn't meet cases with SPOF with AWS volumes in same zone.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk  Thanks for the additional detail.   Will keep your linked in id for future reference.  This is a process for you to manage, not me.  My world is only MySQL and MariaDB performance tuning services. Thanks, Wilson